# Web api performance?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I was thinking ,

The  `WebApi` along with `routing mechanism`  works in such way that it reads the `http verb` ( GET POST etc...) and then searches for matched method names / parameters :

For example :

- If it's `GET`  and the URI is `api/Customers/5`:

  - method should start with `Get`
  - if it has `ID` so search a method which accepts int as  parameter.
  - etc. (there are more rules).

I mostly believe they did it using reflection.

**Question :**

Isn't it a performance hit , for every URI request - to search all this data just to attach a method ?

Where I could easily send a very short string from a client which will imply on the method on the server side ?

*Why not doing it the simple way ? Ok cause we want to use http verbs as meaning. OK. but so much operations just to execute a method*

**example #1**

`get api/Customers/5`

could be

`a.ashx?m=gc&id=5 (method=GetCustomer  & id=5)`

**example #2**

`put api/Customers/5?v=123`

could be

`a.ashx?m=uc&id=5?v=123' (method=UpdateCustomer  & id=5 & value=123)`

mine is even shorter.

Dont get me wrong. I believe this api was done by very smart people who knew what they talk about.

Just want o know what am I missing.

Comment: if it's speed you're looking for, I would extremely suggest that you have a look at [**ServiceStack**](http://www.servicestack.net/)... I did and never used WebApi again :)

Comment: @balexandre Just wondering what everyone is talking about this API...I tried it yesterday  in it is cool. but hey , why not doing it the simple way ? Ok cause we want to use http verbs as meanning. OK. but so much operations just to execute a method ?

Comment: I even prefer WCF Webservices over this new Web API

Comment: The ASP.NET Web API isn't meant to replace the standard webservices. It is designed to support [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and some other modern web standards like content negotiation etc. If you don't want to follow REST principles (where verbs are supppose to have meaning and be used properly) than you most probably doesn't need Web API - it is just a case of using proper tool for proper job.

Comment: @tpeczek Did I say something about webservices ? (which uses soap protocol and very heavy ....) ? I can send command without webservice .... you know.,..to a handler with exactly what ive written above.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I rather meant web services here as a more general concept of services available through HTTP - that could be not precises so sorry for that. The key here is that ASP.NET Web API is designed to resolve concrete architectural approach which is REST (if you looked at the link I have put in my comment you should already know that what you have written above has nothing to do with RESTful web services).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Web api has a lot of options that you don't have with HTTP Handler if you don't code it
Full list: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc317096197

- OData support (via Queryable attribute)
- Content Negotiation
- Filters
- Model binding and validation
- Ability to self host outside of IIS
- Link generation to related resources that incorporates routing rules
- Full support for routes/routing
- Ability to create custom help and test pages using IApiExplorer

Performance comparison HttpHandler vs WebAPI: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Sep/04/ASPNET-Frameworks-and-Raw-Throughput-Performance

As always, you need to choose the the technology that suits you best, if you want performance go with Http Handler. If you want flexibility and rest go with Web API. You might want rest if you expose web services that other will consume

Comment: If you are asking if you can use Web API from Web Forms, the answer is yes. Take a look: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/23/using-asp-net-web-api-with-asp-net-web-forms.aspx

Comment: Thanks. that wasn't my question. Q :  Can I use the features you mentioned in webforms using the downloaded package of MVC ?

Comment: I didn't use all of them, but I think that you can use all of them.