# Web Api Performance gain over MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a MVC web application and I make some ajax calls from the client to get back json data. Right now I just use MVC Action methods to return this data. I was wondering if I should be using the ASP.Net Web Api for these.

I understand that if I was building a REST solution I should be using it.

But in this case would it be justified to add the extra complexity? Is there any speed gain? I don't really need the Content Negotiation feature or the OData Support.

Answer (score 2):

According to the post here (and the benchmark it references), Web API is a bit faster. [Web api performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685713/web-api-performance)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.net Web api support both JSON and xml. Web Api is for implement rest web service on top of MVC application. It would add extra complexity for the application but you implement web api related method in separate controller.

Rest web services are usually faster than Normal SOAP web services.

In your case if your clients are just a web client no need to implement web services. But If you need to share service for different client (widows applications, windows services, third party applications) implement rest service using web API

Comment: Web API does not build on top of MVC.  It is independent.